# Two buttons calling method on the same div using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here, I want to print either"hi" or  "hello" on div1 when button are clicked respectively.

```
<buton onclick="abc('hi')"></button>
<button onclick="abc('hello')"></button>
<div id="div1"></div>

<script>
abc(text){
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Note:Either "hi" or "hello" on div1

Comment: Learn to use quotes properly (nest quotes) i.e. `onclick="abc('hi')"` and `getElementById("div1")`

Comment: Please do not update question based on the comments/suggestions. That would render them useless. It took me a while to understand that you have updated question based on Satpal's suggestion

Comment: Please take care of Note before answering.

Comment: Your issue is trivial syntax errors. As @Rajesh mentioned, reading of textbook would solve your problems. And check your console in browser next time, it can be very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few syntax errors in your code:

- Some quotes in the onClick attribute where wrong. You can't use the same quotes in quotes (wrong: `="func("text")"`  right `="func('text')"`)
- Your function `abc` was not defined as a function
- `getElementById(div1)` you have to use quotes for `div1`. It was looking for a variable.

```js
function abc(text){
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abc('hi')">hi</button>
<button onclick="abc('hello')">hello</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: And what were they? Please explain what and why have you changed. Also please check if the issues that you are pointing out are not addressed by others already

Comment: Please take care of Note addressed below.

Comment: you are right. I added them now. I hope I didn't miss one out.

Comment: If you are not happy with my code please explain your note I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet. (See all quotes and spellings)

```js
function abc(text){  // Added 'function' keyword so javascript can recognize a function has started
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = text;  // add " " before and after div1.  getElementById() takes a string argument and strings are wrapped within " "
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abc('hi')"></button> <!-- onclick() takes string argument wrapped within " " .. function abc() also takes string argument. strings are wrapped within " " or '' (double and single Quotes) -->
<button onclick="abc('hello')"></button> <!-- Same as above -->
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why have you changed? Please explain. You are answering for readers and not just OP

Comment: Sir, I know what the issue is and what have you changed. My point was there are all sort of people on SO. Experts and beginners. So specifying what and why have you changed will help them understanding the mistake